# Mockito when andReturn cannot return expected result

Tags: mockito

I m writing a unit test to test the controller. However, I tried to use Mockito when...andReturn(true) to make the function return true but I still cannot pass the test.

```
@Test
public void testingFunc() throws Exception{
    Mockito.when(testingService.create(userId, deviceId, requestIP, userAgent,"test","test")).thenReturn(true);
    
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/test")
              .param("id","testing")
     .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
     .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
     .andReturn();
     String response = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
     assertEquals("success", response);     
}



@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/test")
@ResponseBody
public String response(String id){
    boolean result = testingService.create(userId, Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(deviceId.getBytes()), 
            request.getRemoteAddr(), Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(userAgent.toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))), "test", "test");
    if(result) return "success";
    return "fail";
}
```

Comment: Is the parameter in your mock method matches the real calling parameter?

Comment: Is it need to be match with the real method?

Comment: I checked the parameter, it should be match with the real method. However, it still cannot make the method return true

Comment: In this line: `Mockito.when(testingService.create(userId, deviceId, requestIP, userAgent,"test","test")).thenReturn(true);`, you are saying that only when the calling parameter equals the given parameter ,this is method return true. If you don't care the parameter,you can use `Mockito.any()`to replace all the parameter in `when`.

Comment: Did you use `verify()` to check that the mock method is really called?

Comment: Ok.. thanks. Let me try it first, Thank you

Comment: Thank you. when I changed to use any(). It solved the problem. Thanks haoyu

Comment: I woud appreciate if you mark my answer as useful.

Comment: Is it possible to make some parameter to use Mockito.any() and some parameters not using Mockito.any() and set it as a String value?

Comment: Mockito.when(testingService.create(userId, deviceId, Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(true) , when I change the code to this it becomes error again

Comment: Somehow Mockito does not allow use value and argument together, you have to use `eq` matcher. Here is a [tutorial](https://dzone.com/refcardz/mockito?chapter=5).

Comment: One more question.. if there contains a string[], Mockito.anyString() seems not work

Comment: Just use `any()`